# Suppress Printing for Custom Structures in Julia

Tags: printing, julia, structure

I have a structure that ends up having a lot of circular references. It resembles this:

```
mutable struct Friend
a                    :: Int64
b                    :: Float64
your_best_friend     :: Union{Nothing, Friend}
you_are_best_friend  :: Union{Nothing, Friend}
Friend() = new()
end
```

Any two people who are best friends with each other will cause a circular reference when this is printed. Julia handles these circular references so that the print doesn't go forever, but I would prefer to have no printing at all whenever a variable of the structure Friend is created. I know supressor.jl is a thing, but I am wondering if there is a solution inherent to Base Julia. Basically, is there an option for structures so that the object isn't printed when assigned without using an extra package? If not, what's the next best thing? I am not a CS guy, so I'm not sure what kind of computation time printing takes, but I'd like to avoid it if possible (and I'm not sure supressor.jl removes the printing time or if printing still takes extra time but just isn't displayed). This seems simple to me, but I can't find the solution in the docs. Sorry if it is obvious and thanks in advance!

-J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overload Base.show to change how objects are shown by the REPL:

```
julia> mutable struct Friend
   a                    :: Int64
   b                    :: Float64
   your_best_friend     :: Union{Nothing, Friend}
   you_are_best_friend  :: Union{Nothing, Friend}
   Friend() = new()
   end

julia> Friend()
Friend(0, 0.0, #undef, #undef)

julia> import Base.show

julia> show(io::IO, f::Friend) = show(io, "Friend $(f.a)")
show (generic function with 223 methods)

julia> d = Friend()
"Friend 0"
```

Note if you also want to change how things print outside the REPL command line, you may also need to overload printing via `import Base.print`

Comment: That worked! Perfect answer for my question and works when just put into the module under the structure definitions. Thanks so much! Great tool to have for the future as well.